# CSS3 slide down menu on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to build a menu that is CSS only. No jQuery.

I've gotten this far but can't make the menu slide in from the top. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ame5wcu/3/) (oddly enough, it doesn't look like my menu... but all the styles are there)

Some code: The HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="blue"> <a style="text-decoration: none" href="/who-we-are">Who We Are</a>

        </li>
        <li class="red"> <a style="text-decoration: none" href="/services">Services</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <a href="/post1" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Post 1">Post 1</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="/post2" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Post 2">Post 2</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="/post3" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Post 3">Post 3</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="orange"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="/packages">Packages</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <a href="/post1" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Post 1">Post 1</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="/post2" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Post 2">Post 2</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="/post3" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Post 3">Post 3</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="green"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="/contact-us">Contact</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.menu {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.blue, div.item.blue div {
    color: #009dc4;
}
.red, div.item.red div {
    color: #fe4f00;
}
.orange, div.item.orange div {
    color: #ff5958;
}
.green, div.item.green div {
    color: #50c402;
}
.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    padding-top: 18px;
}
.menu ul li a:visited {
    color: inherit;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 145px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 46px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
    z-index: 5000;
}
.menu ul li:hover {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
.menu ul li.blue:hover {
    background-color: #009dc4;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #009dc4;
}
.menu ul li.red:hover {
    background-color: #fe4f00;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fe4f00;
}
.menu ul li.orange:hover {
    background-color: #ff5958;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ff5958;
}
.menu ul li.green:hover {
    background-color: #50c402;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #50c402;
}
.menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
}
.menu ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 145px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 0px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: normal;
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
}
.menu ul li ul li a {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #4fc7c1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s;
    transition: all 0.1s;
}
.menu ul li ul li a:hover {
    background: #a3edf5;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.menu > ul > li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

If someone can just help with getting the slide down to work, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Your JS Fiddle doesn't appear to attempt to include any 'slide' logic, it merely implements a 'show/hide' technique. From this standpoint you really should have tried something first rather than simple asked the community to produce a complete solution for you. This aside, I have whipped something up for you (answer below).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mmnUT/

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-smooth-drop-down-menu

Comment: @Le-roy: Please do have a look at all my other questions. I am not someone who just posts here for the sake of posting here. So if you have a non-constructive post that you would like to add, please do so on some spam forum and not here, as you are wasting my time. Thanks.

Comment: @Maddy, thanks, will have a look at it. That actually has a really nice effect to it. Much better than just a slide.

Comment: @DarkRanger all you had to do was google "css3 slide down menu" and you would have found a better starting point. I don't feel I need to evaluate everyone's posts here before I make a comment. It just didn't seem like you had made any effort. Perhaps my assumption was wrong; but you have your answer in any case. Enjoy.

Comment: @Le-roy, you don't have to and I'm not expecting you to, but don't assume. Thanks for the answer. It works perfectly.

Comment: @DarkRanger you are welcome; Don't mean to offend, was just speaking my mind =) take care and hope it works out. -Le-roy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to animate `height:0` to `height:auto` with CSS (as of CSS3). However there is a workaround using `max-height` documented here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/

With that logic I have created a simple example from your JS fiddle. All it does is set the css style `max-height:0` on the drop-down `<ul>` element, some transitions for the `max-height` css attribute and then a large `max-height` value on menu hover.

Unfortunately the `max-height` must be hard-coded (cannot be auto) so we are limited here; but if you are confident that your menus will never exceed say 500px then you would simply put 500px.

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6ame5wcu/4/

Comment: There isn't a slide down transition happening in your fiddle... wrong link?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to set `max-height:0;` and  `overflow:hidden;` then add a `transition` on it like this:

```
.menu ul li ul {
    max-height:0em;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    transition:max-height .9s ease
}
```

on `:hover` set a `max-height` ie `max-height:600px;`

```
.menu ul li:hover ul {
    max-height:600px;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pggsj3vj/1/embedded/result/)

Full code:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="blue"> <a href="/who-we-are">Who We Are</a>

        </li>
        <li class="red"> <a href="/services">Services</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <a href="/post1" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Post 1">Post 1</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="/post2" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Post 2">Post 2</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="/post3" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Post 3">Post 3</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="orange"><a href="/packages">Packages</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <a href="/post1" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Post 1">Post 1</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="/post2" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Post 2">Post 2</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="/post3" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Post 3">Post 3</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="green"><a href="/contact-us">Contact</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
a{text-decoration: none}
.menu {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.blue, div.item.blue div {
    color: #009dc4;
}
.red, div.item.red div {
    color: #fe4f00;
}
.orange, div.item.orange div {
    color: #ff5958;
}
.green, div.item.green div {
    color: #50c402;
}
.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    padding-top: 18px;
}
.menu ul li a:visited {
    color: inherit;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 145px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 46px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
    z-index: 5000;
}
.menu ul li:hover {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
.menu ul li.blue:hover {
    background-color: #009dc4;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #009dc4;
}
.menu ul li.red:hover {
    background-color: #fe4f00;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fe4f00;
}
.menu ul li.orange:hover {
    background-color: #ff5958;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ff5958;
}
.menu ul li.green:hover {
    background-color: #50c402;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #50c402;
}
.menu ul li ul {
    max-height:0em;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    transition:max-height .9s ease
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
    max-height:600px;
}
.menu ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 145px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 0px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: normal;
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
}
.menu ul li ul li a {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #4fc7c1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s;
    transition: all 0.1s;
}
.menu ul li ul li a:hover {
    background: #a3edf5;
}

.menu > ul > li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: It works, but could you provide an explanation about how it works in your answer?